# GraphQL - how to filter a hierarchy? ("customers who ordered gizmos last month")

Tags: graphql

Let's assume a type hierarchy of `Customer -(hasMany)-> Orders -(hasMany)-> OrderLines`

Something like this:

```
Customer {
    Name
    Orders [
        {
            OrderId
            Date
            OrderLines [
                { 
                    ItemCount
                    ItemName
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to query for this whole tree, and *filter* on properties at *any level* in the tree.

For instance: Get all customers who ordered 'gizmos'.

This is what I tried: at each level of the hierarchy, I specify optional arguments that would filter based on the properties available at that level:

```
Customer (Name) {
    Name
    Orders (OrderId, Date) [
        {
            OrderId
            Date
            OrderLines (ItemCount, ItemName) [
                { 
                    ItemCount
                    ItemName
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

GraphQL needs me to define *how to resolve* each type in the hierarchy, so when resolving, I filter based on the arguments in the query.

*But what if I only specify a filter at a deep level?* e.g. `ItemName : 'gizmo'`

Assuming there's only one order line in the system containing a gizmo, I would expect to get a response like this:

```
[{
    Name: "cust12",
    Orders [{
        OrderId: "ade32f",
        OrderLines: [{
            ItemCount: 50000, //customer really likes gizmos
            ItemName: "gizmo"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

But what I actually get is **all** customers (no filter there), **all** their orders (no filter there) and **all** order items, mostly empty (the items inside are filtered).

```
[{
    Name: "cust12",
    Orders [
    {
        OrderId: "aaaaaa",
        OrderLines: [ ]
    },
    {
        OrderId: "ade32f",
        OrderLines: [{
            ItemCount: 50000,
            ItemName: "gizmo"
        }]
    },
    {
        OrderId: "bbbbbb",
        OrderLines: [ ]
    },
    {
        OrderId: "cccccc",
        OrderLines: [ ]
    }
    ]
},
{
    Name: "cust345",
    Orders [
    {
        OrderId: "eeeeee",
        OrderLines: [ ]
    },
    {
        OrderId: "ffffff",
        OrderLines: [ ]
    }
    ]
}]
```

GraphQL calls the resolvers *top-down*:
- get all (filtered) clients
- for each of these get all (filtered) orders
- for each of those get all (filtered) order lines

Because of the top-down nature of calling the resolvers, I get a lot more data than I bargained for.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Relation filters

This is actually a more complex topic than it first seems. The problem is that your current filter condition expresses

> get all customers, but only include items named 'gizmo'

but what you really want is

> get all customers that are related to at least one item named 'gizmo'

### get all customers that are related to at least one item named 'gizmo'

An elegant solution for this problem is the addition of *relation filters* to the schema. In your case, it could look like this:

```
query {
  Customer(filter: {
    orders_some: {
      orderLines_some: {
        item: {
          itemName: "gizmo"
        }
      }
    }
  }) {
    Name
    Orders {
      OrderId
      Date
      OrderLines { 
        ItemCount
        ItemName
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using

```
orders_some: {
  orderLines_some: {
    item: {
      itemName: "gizmo"
    }
  }
}
```

we only fetch customers that are indirectly related to an item named 'gizmo', exactly what we wanted.

Two more examples:

### get all customers that are not related to any item named 'gizmo'

```
query {
  Customer(filter: {
    orders_none: {
      orderLines_some: {
        item: {
          itemName: "gizmo"
        }
      }
    }
  }) {
    Name
    Orders {
      OrderId
      Date
      OrderLines { 
        ItemCount
        ItemName
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### get all customers where all their orders contain some order line with an item named 'gizmo'

```
query {
  Customer(filter: {
    orders_every: {
      orderLines_some: {
        item: {
          itemName: "gizmo"
        }
      }
    }
  }) {
    Name
    Orders {
      OrderId
      Date
      OrderLines { 
        ItemCount
        ItemName
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `every`, `some` and `none` relation filters are an essential part of the Graphcool APIs - you can [read more here](https://www.graph.cool/docs/tutorials/designing-powerful-apis-with-graphql-query-parameters-aing7uech3#expressing-even-complex-data-requirements).

Comment: I actually thought about *hierarchical* filters at the top level (or at all levels), in order to have the full context when resolving types - but was afraid this may be abusing it. Your explanation and link are awesome!