# Does GraphQL support server-side filtering (i.e. building of WHERE-like queries on client side)?

Tags: web-services, graphql, api-design

I'm investigating a possibility to use GraphQL between React.js client application and server application which is built on top of relational SQL database. A query should be created on client side including complex SQL-style statements like:

```
WHERE Customer.Age BETWEEN 22 AND 25
AND   Order.Status = 'Active'
OR    Product.Name LIKE '%foo%'
```

It means the client should usually receive only a small subset of records (for example 10 instead of 10M).

This looking-good [Phil Sturgeon article](https://philsturgeon.uk/api/2017/01/24/graphql-vs-rest-overview/) declares strange things:

> I was hoping GraphQL could help clients define their own scopes,
>   filtering these includes to be the appropriate data themselves, which
>   would help identify the scoped includes the API should add as
>   convenience methods.
>
> It seems like GraphQL doesn't help API developers in this instance,
>   but there does seem to be talk of adding @filter to do this in the
>   future.

In the future? No filtering in GraphQL right now? I continued research and have found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41862789/graphql-how-to-filter-a-hierarchy-customers-who-ordered-gizmos-last-month) and this [amazing interactive Graphcool documentation](https://www.graph.cool/docs/tutorials/designing-powerful-apis-with-graphql-query-parameters-aing7uech3/). Both examples use a feature called `filter` with a set of postfixes like `_gte`:

```
query combineMovies {
  allMovies(filter: {
    OR: [{
      AND: [{
        releaseDate_gte: "2009"
      }, {
        title_starts_with: "The Dark Knight"
      }]
    }, {
      title: "Inception"
    }]
  }) {
    title
    releaseDate
  }
}
```

However, there is no specification for the `filter` keyword at http://graphql.org.
I even checked [Relay](https://facebook.github.io/relay/) docs and have found no good examples of complicated filtering (maybe because of I have no React experience).

Please clarify GraphQL's abilities to build complex SQL WHERE-like queries. Is it a part of standard or just a weakly supported side feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I continued research and have found this SO question and this [amazing interactive Graphcool documentation](https://www.graph.cool/docs/tutorials/designing-powerful-apis-with-graphql-query-parameters-aing7uech3/).

Thanks for the kind words! I'm the author of this article, glad it was helpful! Let me answer your question from the perspective of the Graphcool API.

## GraphQL queries and fields

GraphQL queries are built using fields. Here we use the `id` field defined on the `allMovies` field:

```
query allMovies {
  allMovies {
    id
  }
}
```

I recommend reading [this article](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/the-anatomy-of-a-graphql-query-6dffa9e9e747) for more information on the terminology surrounding GraphQL queries.

## Query Arguments

GraphQL defines so called [query arguments](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/#sec-Language.Arguments) that can be attached to fields. These arguments encode additional information for the GraphQL Server and influence how the field will be resolved. A common example is the `first` query argument:

```
query firstMovie {
  allMovies(first: 1) {
    id
  }
}
```

## Is filtering part of the specification or just a side feature?

Lets investigate further!

```
query darkKnightMovies {
  allMovies(filter: {
    title_contains: "Dark Knight"
  }) {
    id
  }
}
```

In the above query, `filter` is an argument to the `allMovies` field. The syntactical aspect of this is defined in the GraphQL specification as seen above. However, GraphQL doesn't specify how this argument should alter the resolving of the `allMovies` field. This is only determined by the changed behaviour of the resolver for the `allMovies` field in the GraphQL backend.

## Conclusion

GraphQL provides all the necessary **concepts** (queries, fields, arguments) to support server-side filtering. However, **using these concepts** to encode specific behaviour like filtering is up to the developer that creates a GraphQL API.

Comment: This begs the question of what the developer needs to do on the server side to receive the query parameters - I'm really struggling to find information about that

Answer (score 0):

Graphql is a specification and there are different client and server implementations like Apollo, Graphcool, Relay. The code you pasted in your question is client side query and it is a bit complex.In my opinion it is closer to query builder than a query itself.

Graphql queries can be as simple or complex as you like, it is totally up to you assuming you are writing your own server.

You can send simple key value pairs to your server and build an database query in the resolver function on the server side and feed the query to database to get data. Or you can build well formatted queries on the client side and directly feed these queries to database in your resolver function without even touching it. I think graqhcool chooses second approach.

So basically three steps involved:

1. Client sends some query, basically it is a GET or POST request with serialized text,
2. Resolver function on the server picks it up and gets the requested data from the database
3. and returns a response hence resolves the request.

Specification may not speak about filtering because it is implementation detail (it is just a parameter name you use in your post request), though it does, just read pagination section.

For a starter, specification may be a bit abstract, so starting with implementation server like Apollo Server may be better better approach and easier way to learn graphql.